# Making the image alt text look almost identical on all browsers

Tags: css, reactjs, image, object, alt

Using React, I'm working on an email template. The email gets my company's logo. We don't want the image saved locally or remotely, so I decided to use base64. Unfortunately base64 doesn't work on all email clients (I'm looking at you gmail). 
For now, I will be using an alt text with custom styling on it (later I will be looking at email attachment options with express-mailer and nodemailer).

The problem with alt text is that each browser displays it slightly differently. Chrome & Edge display the broken image icon, Safari, Outlook App display a border around the alt text.

I want the alt text to look almost identical on all browsers and email clients

I've tried a couple of things.

__

1. I tried to get rid of the broken image icon with an onerror in my img tag
2. I tried using componentDidMount
3. I tried using the object element to wrap around the img tag, which by default doesn't display anything when an error occurs. With the object tag, I tried adding the alt text within the tags   ALT Text .
   I've also tried using the pseudo selector ::after to the object tag

Nothing worked :(

1.

```
<img src="src.png" alt"Logo text here" onerror="this.style.display='none'"/>
```

2.

```
componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(function(img){
    img.onerror = function(){this.style.display='none';};
   })
  });
}
```

3.

```
<object data="src.png" type="image/png">
  <img src="src.png" alt"Logo text here" />
</object>
```

3.

```
<object data="src.png" type="image/png">
  <img src="src.png" alt"Logo text here" />
  Logo text here
</object>
```

3.

```
<object data="src.png" type="image/png">
  <img src="src.png" />
</object>

object::after {
 content: "Logo text here";
}
```

Nothing worked :/

I'd appreciate some help and I hope what I am asking for makes sense and is doable.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using this css:

```css
img {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 2;
  text-align: center;

  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

img:after {
  content: "\f1c5"" " attr(alt);

  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  color: rgb(100, 100, 100);

  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<img src="./test.jpg" alt="test"/>
```

Note: Font-awesome is missing in this context you can include it to check.

Comment: Images cannot have pseudo-elements.

Comment: Can you please run the sinppet and let me know if it works or not? @Paulie_D